# why will the following error occur during compilation

Tags: c, cc

As part of my program, I used following code:

```
///////////////
98:::printf("%d",abc->stv)
//////////////
100::if(abc)
//////////////
```

(the following error was produced)

```
Possible null pointer dereference: abc - otherwise it is redundant to check if abc is null at line 100
```

Comment: Are you sure it is an error? It is probably a warning. `if(abc)` is equivalent to `if(abc != NULL)` If you could access `abc->stv` at line 98, it means that `abc` is for sure non-null.

Comment: @Benoit, why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: @Winston Ewert: Because I am not sure this is an answer to the question as I did not understand what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 3):

`if (abc)` tests whether `abc` is a null pointer or not.

The compiler is warning you that you've already assumed that `abc` is not a null pointer (by dereferencing it on line 98), which means either

- the `if (abc)` test is redundant (because it will never be true) or
- the dereferencing of `abc` on line 98 is potentially incorrect because `abc` might in fact be null.

Answer (score 2):

If you test for `abc` it means to the compiler it might be null. Therefore dereferencing the pointer like in `abc->stv` is a possible error. A solution is to enclose the `printf` code inside the `if`block:

```
if(abc)
{
    printf("%d",abc->stv)
    ...
}
```